# Get Numbers On Array Play Game with Numbers and Get Next Numbers On Array

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to make a little game for my self.
first i have an arrays.

After this i want to play flip coin game with this data after it runs 1,2 or 3 wins.
After this code

```
import random
rows = [[20,30,40],[30,40,50],[50,20,30]]

#Get number to veribals
player1 = rows[0][0]
player2 = rows[0][1]
player3 = rows[0][2]

coin = [1,2]

print(player1)
print(player2)
print(player3)

game_on = False
total_game = player1 + player2 + player3
while not game_on:

    flip_coin = random.choice(coin)
    player1_flip = random.choice(coin)
    player2_flip = random.choice(coin)
    player3_flip = random.choice(coin)

    print(total_game)

    # Testing Code
    print(f"Total Game Left {total_game}")
    print(f"Computer : {flip_coin}")
    print(f"Player 1 : {player1_flip} Player 2 : {player2_flip} Player 3 : {player3_flip}")
    print(f"Player 1 Left Points : {player1} Player 2 Points : {player2} Player 3 Points : {player3}")

    if player1_flip == flip_coin:
        if player1 == 0:
            pass
        else:
            player1 -= 1
    if player2_flip == flip_coin:
        if player2 == 0:
            pass
        else:
            player2 -= 1
    if player3_flip == flip_coin:
        if player3 == 0:
            pass
        else:
            player3 -= 1
    total_game = player1 + player2 + player3
    if total_game == 1:
        game_on = True






if player1 == 1:
    print("Player 1 is Won")
elif player2 == 1:
    print("Player 2 is Won")
elif player3 == 1:
    print("Player 3 is Won")
```

After this come, how can move next array [30,40,50] and [50,20,30].
After all done, i need get 1. Game Player 1 won, 2. Game player 2 won ect.

How can i do it ?

Comment: You seem to know about the `while` loop. Have you come across any other types of loops? There are a few solutions, but they involve loops. What have you thought about doing?

Comment: Hi, this code only runs [20,30,40], how can i also run [30,40,50],[50,20,30] in rows array

Comment: put all the code inside loop at the beginning that iterates `i` from 0 to 2. Then do `player1 = rows[i][0]` (same for player2 and 3)

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki in this case it says TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to wrap most of your code in a for loop:

```py
import random
rows = [[20,30,40],[30,40,50],[50,20,30]]

for row in rows
    #Get number to veribals
    player1 = row[0]
    player2 = row[1]
    player3 = row[2]

    ...
    # rest of code indented here like this:
    coin = [1,2]
```